# How do I make it so no matter how many times the user presses enter with a blank string, it always prints the 'start' string?

Tags: c++

This is my code -
   How do I make this loop unlimited?
   Like any terminal when you press enter with a blank string it rewrites your root

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

std::string input_t;
void startup(std::string start) {
    std::cout << start;
    while(true) {
        while ( n = std::cin.get() ) {
            if ( int n == (int)'\n' ) {
                   std::cout << start;
                   std::cin >> input_t;
               }
               else {
                   std::cout << "Program is terminating...\n";
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {    
    startup("User:DESKTOP$ ");
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: You may be looking for [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to keep reading in strings up to a newline:

```
while(std::getline(std::cin, input_t))
{
  if (line.empty())
  {
    std::cout << start;
    continue;
  }
  // else do stuff with input_t, or break
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I am 14 trying to make a console so this is a learning experience.